# How can i assign start level of osgi modules?

Tags: netbeans, module, osgi

I am developing netbeans platform application that includes Netbeans and OSGi modules also. I need to assign starting level for OSGi modules.

I could not find any solution to this in Netbeans platform. I have found things like ; OpenIDE-Module-Requires, felix.startlevel.bundle MODULE_START_LEVEL. But either they are not working or i could not find any sample to apply.

In Eclipse, it was easy to assign start level for osgi bundles via run configuration. But there is nothing something like that in Netbeans.

Is there any solution for it ?

Comment: You do NOT need to assign loading order. You maybe think that you want to determine which module to install first, but you do not. It would be easier to explain this if you first explain why you believe that you need to do it.

Comment: I just want to start(BundleActivator.start) some modules aftersome other module's have been started.

Comment: Ah, that's a bit different from what you originally asked. Fine. You can use the startlevel service as BJ says. But you really should still try to manage your bundles so they don't rely on a particular start order... it's so fragile!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relying on start order in OSGi is a red herring since dependencies can come and go. A lot of people think the startlevel service serves this purpose but it does not. The purpose of the startlevel service is for special features like a splash screen or provide an optimization; sometimes you can prevent extra work if you start in a certain order.

What you seem to want to do is take a shortcut. Instead of proper handling of your dependencies (which is quite easy with Declarative Services DS) you as a developer decides that if A, B, and C are running you can start C. Though this works initially it fails when you update A, B, or C since at that moment C is still assuming its dependencies are alive.

In general trying to control start order is a disaster in the long run. It is a lot easier to just use DS and manage the dependencies. Then your code will work in all circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As you said before ; we tried declarative services approach. But, in netbeans, embedded felix does not support DS.So, how can we add Felix Service Component Runtime to embedded felix in netbeans.

Comment: Also add the Apache Felix SCR bundle. DS is not some builtin feature, it is just another bundle ...

Comment: We tried this approach before. It only works when we run the project as osgi>run-in-felix. But when we get zip distribution of project via netbeans, it does not work.

Comment: I would consider this a bug in Netbeans? Did you report it?

Comment: Felix SCR and OSGI CMPN jars should add to project as a cluster and it works. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot assign the order in which installed bundles are resolved. A resolved bundle can have a class loader and classes can then be loaded from it. You can have some control over that start order of bundles by using the [startlevel package](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r5/core/org/osgi/framework/startlevel/package-summary.html).